# update is not working using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I’m facing a problem in SQL Join and Update. Have tried different combinations of ">=" / "=" / "<", but never obtaining the intended result.

```
Table: 'punchdata'
Id      empID    pType        pDate       pTime     pInOut    DeleteRec 
32382   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  08:50:45  In        0
33540   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  12:34:21  Out       0
33171   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:13:49  Out       0
33170   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:09:49  Out       0
33168   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:11:18  In        0
33036   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  12:34:32  Out       0

SQL Statement:
update punchdata w1
  join ( select min(id) as SIMPLEID, `empID`, `pDate`, `pTime`
  from punchdata where pType = 'Attendance' AND pDate = '2021-11-26'
  group by `empID`,`pDate`,`pTime` ) w2
on w1.id > w2.SIMPLEID
and w1.`empID` = 'EMP-217'
and w1.`pDate` = w2.`pDate`
and w1.`pTime` <= w2.`pTime`
and w1.`pInOut` = 'Out'
set w1.`DeleteRec` = '1'

Result:

Id      empID    pType        pDate       pTime     pInOut    DeleteRec
32382   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  08:50:45  In        0
33540   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  12:34:21  Out       1
33171   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:13:49  Out       0
33170   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:09:49  Out       1
33168   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:11:18  In        0
33036   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  12:34:32  Out       0

Intended Output:
Id      empID    pType        pDate       pTime     pInOut    DeleteRec
32382   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  08:50:45  In        0
33540   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  12:34:21  Out       1
33171   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:13:49  Out       0
33170   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:09:49  Out       1
33168   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  17:11:18  In        0
33036   EMP-217  Attendance   2021-11-26  ***12:34:32  Out       1***
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: you've provided a lot of very helpful information for your question, but could you also add a brief English description of what it is you want your update to do?

Comment: one thing that strikes me is that you are not joining on w2.empID, so the w2 SIMPLEID could be for any empID

Comment: There's no `pType` column in the table.

Comment: Made corrections to the tables and added intended action

Comment: "I want to find out the maximum of pTime with a given date and ID and mark the rest as 1 and leaving the maximum as 0 in DeleteRec." but only Out records?  by date and ID, which ID do you mean, the empID?  we really could help you much better with a clearer understanding than your query (that does *not* do what you want) will give; please say in full in English what you are trying to do, with enough details to write the query without needing to look at your attempt.

Comment: Yes please...I want to find out the maximum of pTime with a given pDate="2021-11-26', empID='emp-217' and for pInOut='Out' and mark the rest as 1 and leaving the maximum as 0 in DeleteRec.

Comment: I do not know why the question is given a -2 score. People with power of doing so need to put a comment so that learning can increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you decide that the row `id=33036` should be updated?

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6898a4303740dfd69c2fc72f2e0b40d). None row with `w1.id=33036` have all 5 criteria equal to TRUE (see `criteria_1` and `criteria_4`, at least one of them is FALSE).

Comment: Basically I want to find out the maximum of pTime with a given date and ID and mark the rest as 1 and leaving the maximum as 0 in DeleteRec. Trying to build it in the fiddle. if you can please help...

Comment: Solved it... update punchdata w1
  join ( select 'id', `empID`, `pDate`, `pTime`
  from punchdata where pType = 'Attendance' AND pDate = '2021-11-26'
  group by `empID`,`pDate`,`pTime` ) w2
on w1.`empID` = 'EMP-217'
and w1.`pDate` = w2.`pDate`
and w1.`pTime` < w2.`pTime`
and w1.`pInOut` = 'Out'
set w1.`DeleteRec` = '1'